# Multiclass Classification: SVM "1vs1" versus "1vsAll"

Tags: svm, libsvm

Say there are 10 classes. If I use 1vs1, then there are 45 comparisons (SVMs) in training. If I use 1vsAll, then there are 10 (1vs-1)SVMs. However, the computation burden for the latter case is actually much higher, because the kernel matrix in each SVM is much larger.

My question is: in my implementation of SVM for multiclass classification, the accuracy using 1vsall is no better than that of 1vs1. There is also some online source shows same observation. Then, in which conditions or aspects does 1vsAll have an advantage? (certainly not time I think, as mentioned above.)

Answer (score 0):

1 vs all always shows one winner. using 1 vs 1 you may run into rock-scissors-paper problems. as probability predictions are definitely not perfect in svm. you have to evaluate which approach is appropriate for your problem. check if the actual classification runtime is a problem in your case.

Comment: It's true that 1vs1 may give an equal number of "winning times", e.g. for a certain instance, class 1 and class 2 both win 8 times out of 9. In this case, we can use SVM score only. However this happens in 1vsAll as well: it's likely that more than 1 class will say the instance is positive.